# Facets of binary polytopes

Tags: linear-algebra, polytopes

I have a problem that seems like it should have a slick, elegant solution but I'm having trouble finding one.

I'm working with convex polytopes with vertices that are subsets of $\{-1,1\}^n$.  When considering the facet-defining hyperplanes 
$$a_1 x_1 + \cdots + a_n x_n + b = 0$$
I'd like to claim that we may assume the coefficients $a_i$ lie in $\{0, \pm 1\}$.

I have a clunky induction argument in mind, but it feels like there may be a shrewd linear algebra trick for something like this.

Thanks!